# no such file to load -- bundler/setup in Rails 3.2 with Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger, bundler

I'm running a vserver on apache2 with passenger.
Using RVM for ruby.
Ruby Version -> 1.9.3p194
Rails Version -> 3.2.3
Set up by Apache Virtual Host Configuration ...

Now, when I'm entering the url into my browser, a passenger error page shows up:

```
no such file to load -- bundler/setup
```

I have no idea what to do now.
Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you using a gemset in RVM?

Comment: have you read the integration docs https://rvm.io/integration/passenger/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` in your root dir and use it to specify the GEM_PATH.

For example:

```
SetEnv GEM_PATH /home/dinduks/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0
```

Comment: This seems to work, but then another Passenger error appears:
Could not find rake-0.9.2.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Comment: Can you approve my answer then?  :) -- Try adding `gem 'rake'` to your Gemfile.

Comment: Approved. But gem 'rake' does not helped with the other problem :(

Comment: Thanks. Did you `bundle install` and restart the server?

Comment: Should the .htaccess file go in Rails root or rails_root/public/ ?

Comment: @David I don't remember exactly, so I checked an old Rails site of mine, and there was a *.htaccess* file on the application root (not *public/*). I'd say in Rails root then.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the bundler gem isn't in your path or isn't installed

Comment: it is installed!
but what do you mean by it isn't in my path?

Comment: it probably has something to do with rvm and passenger. rvm modifies your gem path (where ruby looks for you gems). Either the path is wrong, or bundler is not installed in the gemset that you are using to run passenger.

Comment: yes, make sure that the path that rvm drops your gems in is included in the gem_home variable (i think) that the apache/passenger process environment has

Comment: $GEM_HOME is pointed to this path /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194
. In it there is another gems folder where bunlder-1.1.3 is available. Should $GEM_HOME point to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems?