# Redmine 2 on Hostmonster apache fcgi: Rails application failed to start properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redmine, fastcgi, hostmonster

I have followed [install instructions](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall) until **configuration** section to install redmine 2 on hostmonster.
When running domain.com/redmine I have always 500 error

```
Rails application failed to start properly
```

I havent any log about this error in **log/production.log**. Here is the file:

```
OpenIdAuthentication.store is nil. Using in-memory store.
Creating scope :open. Overwriting existing method Version.open.
Creating scope :active. Overwriting existing method User.active.
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in CollectiveIdea::Acts::NestedSet::Model instead. (called from include at /home1/iptechin/rails_apps/redmine200/lib/plugins/awesome_nested_set/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:58)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in CollectiveIdea::Acts::NestedSet::Model instead. (called from include at /home1/iptechin/rails_apps/redmine200/lib/plugins/awesome_nested_set/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:58)
Creating scope :open. Overwriting existing method Issue.open.
Migrating to Setup (1)
Migrating to IssueMove (2)
Migrating to IssueAddNote (3)
Migration lines...........................etc.........
Migrating to AddAuthSourcesFilter (20120301153455)
Migrating to ChangeRepositoriesToFullSti (20120422150750)
OpenIdAuthentication.store is nil. Using in-memory store.
Creating scope :open. Overwriting existing method Version.open.
Creating scope :active. Overwriting existing method User.active.
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in CollectiveIdea::Acts::NestedSet::Model instead. (called from include at /home1/iptechin/rails_apps/redmine200/lib/plugins/awesome_nested_set/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:58)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in CollectiveIdea::Acts::NestedSet::Model instead. (called from include at /home1/iptechin/rails_apps/redmine200/lib/plugins/awesome_nested_set/lib/awesome_nested_set/awesome_nested_set.rb:58)
Creating scope :open. Overwriting existing method Issue.open.
```

My redmine should work with fcgi, so here is my **public/.htaccess**:

```
# General Apache options
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_cgi.c>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</IfModule>
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_cgi.c>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.cgi [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>Application error</h2>Rails application failed to start properly"
```

And here is my **public/dispatch.fcgi**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/boot'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../config/environment'

class Rack::PathInfoRewriter
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env.delete('SCRIPT_NAME')
    parts = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('?')
    env['PATH_INFO'] = parts[0]
    env['QUERY_STRING'] = parts[1].to_s
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

Rack::Handler::FastCGI.run Rack::PathInfoRewriter.new(RedmineApp::Application)
```

Is there any misconfiguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a gems path issue.
Thanks to this [no such file to load -- bundler/setup in Rails 3.2 with Passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499364/no-such-file-to-load-bundler-setup-in-rails-3-2-with-passenger) I added this line in /public/.htaccess:

```
SetEnv GEM_PATH /path-to-ruby-gems/ruby/gems
```

Answer (score 1):

are all the correct gems installed ?

here is my dispatch.fcgi :

```
   #!/usr/bin/ruby
   #
   # You may specify the path to the FastCGI crash log (a log of unhandled
   # exceptions which forced the FastCGI instance to exit, great for debugging)
   # and the number of requests to process before running garbage collection.
   #
   # By default, the FastCGI crash log is RAILS_ROOT/log/fastcgi.crash.log
   # and the GC period is nil (turned off).  A reasonable number of requests
   # could range from 10-100 depending on the memory footprint of your app.
   #
   # Example:
   #   # Default log path, normal GC behavior.
   #   RailsFCGIHandler.process!
   #
   #   # Default log path, 50 requests between GC.
   #   RailsFCGIHandler.process! nil, 50
   #
   #   # Custom log path, normal GC behavior.
   #   RailsFCGIHandler.process! '/var/log/myapp_fcgi_crash.log'
   #
   require File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment"
   require 'fcgi_handler'

   RailsFCGIHandler.process!
```

and my .htaccess

```
# General Apache options
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler fastcgi-script .fcgi
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
#   AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_cgi.c>
#   AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
</IfModule>
# For security reasons, Option followsymlinks cannot be overridden.
#Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI

# If you don't want Rails to look in certain directories,
# use the following rewrite rules so that Apache won't rewrite certain requests
#
# Example:
#   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/notrails.*
#   RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Redirect all requests not available on the filesystem to Rails
# By default the cgi dispatcher is used which is very slow
#
# For better performance replace the dispatcher with the fastcgi one
#
# Example:
#   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
RewriteEngine On

# If your Rails application is accessed via an Alias directive,
# then you MUST also set the RewriteBase in this htaccess file.
#
# Example:
#   Alias /myrailsapp /path/to/myrailsapp/public
#   RewriteBase /myrailsapp

Options -MultiViews
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
#Change to your environment
RailsEnv production

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^$ index.html [QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
<IfModule mod_fastcgi.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.fcgi [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_cgi.c>
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ dispatch.cgi [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

# In case Rails experiences terminal errors
# Instead of displaying this message you can supply a file here which will be rendered instead
#
# Example:
#   ErrorDocument 500 /500.html

ErrorDocument 500 "<h2>Application error</h2>Rails application failed to start properly"
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^redmine.acme-tech.net$ [OR]
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.redmine.acme-tech.net$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:12018\/$1" [P,L]
```

hope it helps

gj.

Comment: Thanks for sharing files but I do have passenger error now! I think Passenger is not available on Hostmonster. Is it?

Comment: It apparently isn't: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=41623 -- http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=39146

Comment: @Gjergj Shelija Thanks A LOT! You just saved me a lot of hair on my head, i was about to give up with setting up redmine on my server and stay with the local version but thanks to you i got it working :)