# Redmine 404 on some pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, redmine, bluehost

I have installed Redmine on a shared Bluehost account and at first sight it seems to be working.

I followed both of these tutorials: https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/redmine and http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

But just as i started navigating around i noticed that there seem to be a routing problem because some of the pages are returning a 404 error code for a reason i don't understand yet.

The error log shows no information regarding this problem.

The url is on redmine.example.com , the user/pass are still admin/admin.

I have identified that any URL regarding a project is failing, for example:
http://redmine.example.com/projects/new
http://redmine.example.com/projects/21
http://redmine.example.com/projects/21/issues

(Currently i have reset the DB for privacy concerns)

In order to prove my theory that it was regarding the projects issue, i went into the projects controller file found in app/controllers/projects_controller.rb and tried to put some `abort("Foo")` here and there but i couldn't see my message with any of the links that are not working so i thought maybe the problem is not there and is probably in the routing process. So i checked the config/routes.rb file and comparing it with my local version they seem identical

I am not sure what to try next as i am not a Ruby developer. Let me know what kind of info you need in order to help debug this problem.

Comment: any got it working with FastCGI maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually i got it working by using FastCGI.
In order to do that, i simply created a .htaccess file and a dispatcher.fcgi as shown in the answer here : [Redmine 2 on Hostmonster apache fcgi: Rails application failed to start properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10743577/redmine-2-on-hostmonster-apache-fcgi-rails-application-failed-to-start-properly)

Don't forget to SetEnv GEM_PATH to your ruby gems path in your .htaccess file and it should work after restarting (`pkill dispatcher.fcgi`)